# Verify CUDA installation in Ubuntu 18.06

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, cuda

I'm having problem after installing cuda on my computer.

The nvidia-smi command shows me this :

[image]

The nvcc --version command shows me this :

[image]

When I tried to use 'sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit', it installs CUDA version 9.

I would like to set CUDA Version: 11.1 as the default version. And when I use nvcc I would like it to shows me CUDA versions 11.1.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

General instructions for installing CUDA Toolkit 11.4 can be found [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads).

When I used the "deb (network)" installation option, I did NOT see it installed in the expected location (/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin).

However, using the "deb (local)" installation option, I was able to confirm the installation.

After that, it was just a matter of setting up the path to point to the install location, as mentioned in the documentation, [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#faq2):

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
```

After running this, I was able to confirm that the correct version of nvcc was installed:

```
$nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jun__2_19:15:15_PDT_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.4, V11.4.48
Build cuda_11.4.r11.4/compiler.30033411_0
```